# Course unable to link to taxonomy

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I accidentally disabled the [Course](https://www.drupal.org/project/course) module. When I enabled it back, the taxonomy doesn't respond correctly for the course content type. When I add a course it does not link to taxonomy.

When I hit preview while editing a course I see this error message:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Here is the code:

```
foreach($content->taxonomy as $key => $term;){ echo "result"; }
```

I don't think I cause the code problem, because it worked before.  The error only occurred when when I disabled the course module.

How am I link this course back to taxonomy?